# Combine columns from multiple select queries to make single table

Tags: mysql, select

I have two SELECT queries.

TABLE1

[image]

TABLE2

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
SELECT * FROM TABLE2;
```

Both TABLE1,TABLE2 have **one row** and same amount of columns.They don's have any common columns.
I want to crate following table.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this...

**SELECT * FROM TABLE1 tab1,TABLE2 tab2;**

Answer (score 0):

Try the union operator:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```

Also, be aware of the difference between UNION vs UNION ALL: 
[MySQL UNION](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx)

Comment: this will not produce the desired output.. rather it will give the same number of columns with two rows....